# group_by display belongs_to 'name' followed by has_many 'items'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display group name (product_group) followed by the items (product) in each group.

```
<% @products.group_by(&:product_group_id).each do |s|%> 
    <!--need to get group name here ->                                              
    <% s[1].each do |d|%>
    <%= d.product_name%>
    <br>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend using two variables in your block.  When you use one variable, group_by sets the variable to an array of the pair of values which should be set as two variables.  It will be much more clear code than indexing the pair with [1] for the group.

One way is that the first part of the pair will be the id, so you can do a find.

```
<% @products.group_by(&:product_group_id).each do |product_group_id, products|%> 
  <!--need to get group name here -->
  <%= ProductGroup.find(product_group_id).name %>

  <% products.each do |product|%>
    <%= product.product_name%>
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Another way, is since you have an array of at least on product in the group, you can call the product_group association on the first element of the array.

```
<% @products.group_by(&:product_group_id).each do |product_group_id, products|%> 
  <!--need to get group name here -->
  <%= products[0].product_group.name %>

  <% products.each do |product|%>
    <%= product.product_name%>
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also delegate the name to the product group.

```
class Product
  belongs_to :product_group
  delegate :name, :to => :product_group, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
end


<%= products[0].product_group_name %>
```

Comment: thank you very much.  i never knew about delegate before.  i will read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Group by needs two variables in the block declaration. The first for the thing you are grouping by, and the second to hold the things in each of the groups.

```
<% @products.group_by(&:product_group_id).each do |group_id, group_products| %>
  Group ID: <%= group_id %>
  <br>
  Products:
  <% group_products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.product_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: perfect. that's what i was missing.

EDIT: i just noticed now it's displaying the ID from group_id, im guessing that's because of the group_by.   is there a way to get the group_name to display?